# Current User Location return Zero values

Tags: xcode, mapkit, currentlocation

I use a global variable (declared as below )for latitude and longitude because i need to use them in other classes
in .h class :

```
extern NSNumber *MYGlobalVariableLat;
extern NSNumber *MYGlobalVariableLong;
```

Then in .m class:

```
NSNumber *MYGlobalVariableLat;
NSNumber *MYGlobalVariableLong;

MYGlobalVariableLat = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(id)self.mapView.userLocation coordinate].latitude];

MYGlobalVariableLong = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[mapView.userLocation coordinate].longitude];

NSLog(@"Lat %@",MYGlobalVariableLat);
NSLog(@"Long %@",MYGlobalVariableLong);
```

that's always print Zero , Any help please ..